# Elements not displaying correctly across bigger screens

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created a landing page that has a lot of alignment issues on bigger screens, despite having a lot of {margin: auto;} functions. Not sure what is wrong.

Additional issues:
1) small white space to the left of the showcase banner 
2) white space at the bottom of the page, below footer
3) yellow line in the middle should be in line with title (Featured Speaker)
4) Yellow button CTA not wrapping nicely

Any help with anything listed would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

```
 1)

<!-- Showcase Section-->
<div id="showcase">
 <header>
  <nav class="cf">
    <ul class="cf">
      <li class="hide-on-small">
        <a href="https://www.centro.net/">
        <img src="https://www2.centro.net/l/75412/2019-01- 
 15/4kzjqb/75412/179423/Centro_Webinar_logo.png" alt="Centro Webinars"> 
 </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" id='openup'>Centro Webinars</a>
  </nav>
</header>

/* Showcase */
#showcase {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
padding-bottom: 20px;
background: url('https://www2.centro.net/l/75412/2019-01- 
15/4kzjql/75412/179431/herotallerwider.png') no-repeat center/cover;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
overflow-y: hidden;
}

#showcase .container {
margin-top: 13vh;
margin-left: 0vw;
margin-right: 43vw;
}

#showcase h1 {
margin-left: 7vw;
font-size: 1.5rem;
margin-bottom: -0.1em;
color: #1fadde;
}

#showcase h3 {
margin-left: 7vw;
font-size: 0.9rem;
margin-bottom: -1.3em;
color: #3a3d40;
}

 #showcase h2 {
 margin-left: 7vw;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 margin-bottom: -0.5em;
 color: #1fadde;
 }

 #showcase p {
 margin-left: 7vw;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-bottom: -0.5em;
 color: #3a3d40;
 width: 70%;
 }


2)

/* Footer */
footer .footersection {
background: #333;
padding: 1rem;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
#footer img {
margin-top: 0.5vh;
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
display: inline;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: 10px;
}
#footer .smicons {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
}


<!-- Footer Section -->
<footer>  
<section id="footer" class="footersection">
<div class="container">
<div class="smicons">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/centro.llc">
<img src="https://www2.centro.net/l/75412/2019-01- 
16/4kzrcg/75412/179517/facebook.png" alt="Centro Facebook">
</a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/centro">
<img src="https://www2.centro.net/l/75412/2019-01- 
16/4kzrcb/75412/179519/twitter.png" alt="Centro Twitter">
</a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/centro">
<img src="https://www2.centro.net/l/75412/2019-01- 
16/4kzrcd/75412/179515/linkedin.png" alt="Centro LinkedIn">
</a>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/centrollc">
<img src="https://www2.centro.net/l/75412/2019-01- 
16/4kzrcj/75412/179521/youtube.png" alt="Centro YouTube">
</a>
</div>
</div>
</footer>


3)

<!-- Featured Speakers Section -->
<section id="featuredspeakers" class="featuredspeakerssection">
<div class="container">
<div class="featspeak">
<h3 pardot-region="speakerORspeakers" pardot-region- 
type="simple">Featured Speaker
</h3>
</div>  
    <div>
    <hr>
    </div>
<img src="https://www2.centro.net/l/75412/2019-01- 
15/4kzjqj/75412/179433/ryanmancheecirclegoldring.png" alt="Ryan Manchee">
<h4 pardot-region="speaker name" pardot-region-type="simple">[SPEAKER 
 NAME]
</h4>
<h5 pardot-region="speaker title" pardot-region-type="simple">Speaker 
Title
</h5>
<p class="lead" pardot-region="speaker bio1" pardot-region- 
type="simple">Speaker Bio 1</p>
<p class="lead" pardot-region="speaker bio2" pardot-region- 
type="simple">Speaker Bio 2</p>
</div>

/* Feature Speaker Section */
.featuredspeakerssection {
padding: 1rem 0;
}

#featuredspeakers .container {
margin: 0;
margin-top: 1vh;
margin-left: 0vw;
}

#featuredspeakers h3 {
font-size: 1.5rem;
color: #1fadde;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 7vw;
margin-top: 7vh;
}
#featuredspeakers hr { 
display: inline-block;
margin: -50px 50px 75px 20px;
overflow: hidden;
border-style: inset;
border-width: 0.5px;
border-color: #ffbf3d;
width: 80%;
margin-left: 24vw;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 3vh;
position: relative;
}



4)

/* Buttons */
.button {
background-color: #FFBF3D;
border: none;
color: #3a3d40;
padding: 10px 25px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
width: 8%;
font-size: 14px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: -2vh;
border-radius: 5px;
}

<!-- Banner Section -->
<section id="banner" class="bannersection">
<div class="container">
<h3 pardot-region="banner title" pardot-region-type="simple">Catch Up 
With Your Industry</h3>
<p class="lead" pardot-region="banner blurb" pardot-region- 
type="simple">Level up and review our most popular past webinars.</p> 
</div>
<div pardot-region="banner CTA" pardot-region-type="simple" 
href="https://www.centro.net/webinar" class="button">Take Me There
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi User10924715, welcome to Stack Overflow! It appears to me as if you've just pasted you whole or a big part of your code and hope we do your work and fix/improve it. That's now what this site is about. The idea is that you ask a specific question, after you've done some troubleshooting and research yourself. So instead of putting this all here as one giant issue, you can expect far better responses if you clear out your code to the minimal required to reproduce the issue.May I suggest this help page [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, check out [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)  for an introduction to the site.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your showcase banner image is white on the left, so is displaying correctly.

2) You have issues with the opening and closing of section and div tags

3) Just played around with your margins. The current solution will always give varied results on different sized screens because of the fixed size of the speaker's photo. I would look at finding a different solution for the positioning of your yellow hr

4) Changed this div to an anchor because you need it to act like a button.

```css
/* Showcase */

#showcase {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: url('https://www2.centro.net/l/75412/2019-01-15/4kzjql/75412/179431/herotallerwider.png') no-repeat center/cover;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#showcase .container {
  margin-top: 13vh;
  margin-left: 0vw;
  margin-right: 43vw;
}

#showcase h1 {
  margin-left: 7vw;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.1em;
  color: #1fadde;
}

#showcase h3 {
  margin-left: 7vw;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  margin-bottom: -1.3em;
  color: #3a3d40;
}

#showcase h2 {
  margin-left: 7vw;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.5em;
  color: #1fadde;
}

#showcase p {
  margin-left: 7vw;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: -0.5em;
  color: #3a3d40;
  width: 70%;
}


/* Footer */

footer .footersection {
  background: #333;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#footer img {
  margin-top: 0.5vh;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#footer .smicons {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Feature Speaker Section */

.featuredspeakerssection {
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

#featuredspeakers .container {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 1vh;
  margin-left: 0vw;
}

#featuredspeakers h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #1fadde;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 7vw;
  margin-top: 7vh;
}

#featuredspeakers hr {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 0.5px;
  border-color: #ffbf3d;
  margin-left: 40%;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
}


/* Buttons */

.button {
  background-color: #FFBF3D;
  border: none;
  color: #3a3d40;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 8%;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -2vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
1)

<!-- Showcase Section-->
<div id="showcase">
  <header>
    <nav class="cf">
      <ul class="cf">
        <li class="hide-on-small">
          <a href="https://www.centro.net/"><img src="https://www2.centro.net/l/75412/2019-01-15/4kzjqb/75412/179423/Centro_Webinar_logo.png" alt="Centro Webinars"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" id="openup">Centro Webinars</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
2)

<!-- Footer Section -->
<footer>
  <section id="footer" class="footersection">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="smicons">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/centro.llc"><img src="https://www2.centro.net/l/75412/2019-01-16/4kzrcg/75412/179517/facebook.png" alt="Centro Facebook"></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/centro"><img src="https://www2.centro.net/l/75412/2019-01-16/4kzrcb/75412/179519/twitter.png" alt="Centro Twitter">
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/centro"><img src="https://www2.centro.net/l/75412/2019-01-16/4kzrcd/75412/179515/linkedin.png" alt="Centro LinkedIn"></a>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/centrollc"><img src="https://www2.centro.net/l/75412/2019-01-16/4kzrcj/75412/179521/youtube.png" alt="Centro YouTube"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</footer>
3)

<!-- Featured Speakers Section -->
<section id="featuredspeakers" class="featuredspeakerssection">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="featspeak">
      <h3 pardot-region="speakerORspeakers" pardot-region-type="simple">Featured Speaker </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www2.centro.net/l/75412/2019-01-15/4kzjqj/75412/179433/ryanmancheecirclegoldring.png" alt="Ryan Manchee">
    <h4 pardot-region="speaker name" pardot-region-type="simple">[SPEAKER NAME] </h4>
    <h5 pardot-region="speaker title" pardot-region-type="simple">Speaker Title </h5>
    <p class="lead" pardot-region="speaker bio1" pardot-region-type="simple">
      Speaker Bio 1
    </p>
    <p class="lead" pardot-region="speaker bio2" pardot-region-type="simple">
      Speaker Bio 2
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
4)

<!-- Banner Section -->
<section id="banner" class="bannersection">
  <div class="container">
    <h3 pardot-region="banner title" pardot-region-type="simple">Catch Up With Your Industry</h3>
    <p class="lead" pardot-region="banner blurb" pardot-region-type="simple">
      Level up and review our most popular past webinars.
    </p>
  </div>
  <a pardot-region="banner CTA" pardot-region-type="simple" href="https://www.centro.net/webinar" target="_blank" class="button">
        Take Me There
    </a>
</section>
```